# Is it possible to publish aspnet core to shared linux server?

Tags: asp.net, linux

I searched a lot to find any source how to publish.net core projects to free hosting (shared) servers. But I couldn't find anything about it. 
I don't talk about to publish linux vm servers. Free web servers does not have any console. Are they?

I know they use ftp solutions.I couldn't find any article to publish aspnet core to linux public server via ftp.

Is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "shared linux server"? also what server hosting company are you using. Regardless, if it's linux, it has a console, unless whatever companies is stopping you from accessing it. Please update your question and give more information (details) so people can answer your question.

Comment: i.e : https://www.000webhost.com/ Free hosting servers.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would just enable port 22 on your hosting site's config, `scp` your published project to copy it there, then run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet run` on your remote server with `ssh -t`. The particular company you mentioned, 000webhost, only allows ssh on their paid tier, and it looks like they are focused primarily on php and mysql anyways. I would suggest you get an AWS instance, or some other full server hosting company, and move your app there.